# App.config Data Source Relative Path?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, datasource, app-config, relative-path

This is the connection string to a local database on my pc:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataEntities" 
   connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.csdl|res://*/Data.ssdl|res://*/Data.msl;
   provider=System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0;provider connection string=&quot;
   Data Source=C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\incidentapp\incidentapp\Database\Data.sdf&quot;"
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

However I want to move the project back-and-forth between computers. How can I set a relative path to my database if the database is in the project location which is incidentapp.

Comment: did you try removing `"C:\Users\User\Documents\GitHub\incidentapp\incidentapp\"`

Comment: Yes. I also tried `..\incidentapp\incidentapp\Database\Data.sdf` yet the path doesn't work. @DanielA.White

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It's because I'm running debug, therefore the 'default' location is at the debug folder. So I just needed to move the database location to the debug folder when I'm developing.
Thanks.